# Very Delayed Heroku Emails

Tags: heroku, nodemailer

I have a basic set up to send mails using nodemailer and NodeJS. I am using a gmail account to send it.

Everything is working perfectly when running on my local machine. I have a log that sends me an error message or a success message.

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error " + err);
            } else {
                console.log("Email sent successfully");
            }
            });
```

The emails come successfully right when I receive the log, "Email sent successfully" when running everything on my local machine.

When I deploy it onto heroku and run the application, the emails come at random intervals. The email can come anywhere from 5 minutes after to a few hours later after receiving the "Email sent successfully" log in my heroku logs.

Could anyone help me figure out why there is such a big delay on my heroku app?

Comment: There could be several causes. I _strongly_ advise you to stop using Gmail for this. It isn't designed for programmatic email sending like this. Use something like SendGrid or Mailgun instead. They both have free tiers are are much better choices.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I switched from gmail to SendGrid and it works perfectly now.